# Dual Boot menu no longer working

Tags: boot, dual-boot

After being unplugged for a few days my computer no longer wants to show a dual boot menu (with systems windows 11 and  ubuntu) and I'm unsure why.  It currently boots directly into ubuntu.
I've tried holding shift and also holding the down arrow.  This causes the computer to never boot.

I've also tried using boot-repair.  The output logs can be found below.  Any help on what is occurring would be greatly appreciated.

```
Baboot-repair-4ppa2056                                              [20230513_1431]

============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================






Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub-efi of
sdb4,
using the following options:  sdb3/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file restore-efi-backups


rm /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
mv /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1/efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
rm /boot/efi/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
mv /boot/efi/efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /boot/efi/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
sdb4/boot/efi not empty

======================== Reinstall the grub-efi of sdb4 ========================

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.06-2ubuntu7.1
modprobe efivars

efibootmgr -v before grub install
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0002,0000
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,cebfb099-1588-49a0-8c36-aa656fd658f7,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIMICROSOFTBOOTBOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...y................
Boot0002* ubuntu    HD(3,GPT,299318df-05c8-408c-9ae6-26d536f15c5f,0xc45a800,0x100000)/File(EFIUBUNTUSHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,cebfb099-1588-49a0-8c36-aa656fd658f7,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIUBUNTUSHIMX64.EFI)..BO

uname -r
5.19.0-41-generic

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/sdb3
mv /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
df /dev/nvme0n1p1
mv /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

efibootmgr -v after grub install
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0000
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,cebfb099-1588-49a0-8c36-aa656fd658f7,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIMICROSOFTBOOTBOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...y................
Boot0002* ubuntu    HD(3,GPT,299318df-05c8-408c-9ae6-26d536f15c5f,0xc45a800,0x100000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)

update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-41-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-40-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-71-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-71-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sdb4/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS entry (sdb3/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => Windows 7/8/10/11/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Windows 7/8/10/11/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

sdb4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on sdb4
OS#2:   Windows 10 or 11 on nvme0n1p3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: GA106 [GeForce RTX 3060] from NVIDIA Corporation
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-41-generic root=UUID=e6f0548c-16b9-4aaa-959a-c66d9eb76d85 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
df -Th / : /dev/sdb4      ext4  1.7T  1.4T  220G  87% /

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: P1.40(5.17) from American Megatrends Inc.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this installed-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0000
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,cebfb099-1588-49a0-8c36-aa656fd658f7,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...y................
Boot0002* ubuntu    HD(3,GPT,299318df-05c8-408c-9ae6-26d536f15c5f,0xc45a800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)

728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
3795ef72a4ed0369ca44e711527904bf   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bootx64.efi
c152ec201c37b6e97bbc2207e49d1271   nvme0n1p1/Boot/fbx64.efi
fdafb5eece6caeccb788c946a28e6872   nvme0n1p1/Boot/mmx64.efi
3795ef72a4ed0369ca44e711527904bf   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
fdafb5eece6caeccb788c946a28e6872   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
f2c9c5c28ef51a83d75db5d108b1a310   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
46288d3cb6a91cb97d25474930f95dfb   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sdb : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    34 sectors * 512 bytes
nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    34 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sdb4    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
nvme0n1p3   : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p4   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdb2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sdb3    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sdb4    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sdb3    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sdb4    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sdb
nvme0n1p3   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
sdb2    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sdb3    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sda2    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk identifier: 29EBA0EA-3C2C-4457-9792-FAAABF576695
              Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1      2048    206847    204800   100M EFI System
nvme0n1p2    206848    239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3    239616 975749119 975509504 465.2G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4 975749120 976773119   1024000   500M Windows recovery environment
Disk sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 787DEA2B-560B-4C23-B586-B6729437F0E4
      Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
sda1     34      32767      32734    16M Microsoft reserved
sda2  32768 1953521663 1953488896 931.5G Microsoft basic data
Disk sdb: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk identifier: FE46A1DF-A7E9-43A3-A500-C4ACE9C13877
          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
sdb1         34      32767      32734   16M Microsoft reserved
sdb2      32768  205889760  205856993 98.2G Microsoft basic data
sdb3  205891584  206940159    1048576  512M EFI System
sdb4  206940160 3907028991 3700088832  1.7T Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA ST1000DM010-2EP1:;
1:17.4kB:16.8MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
2:16.8MB:1000GB:1000GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
sdb:2000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA ST2000DM008-2FR1:;
1:17.4kB:16.8MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
2:16.8MB:105GB:105GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
3:105GB:106GB:537MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
4:106GB:2000GB:1894GB:ext4::;
nvme0n1:500GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:WDC WDS500G2B0C-00PXH0:;
1:1049kB:106MB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:106MB:123MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:123MB:500GB:499GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:500GB:500GB:524MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL      PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                       
├─sda1                                                    254bced3-1322-4dc5-ad3c-4d61681c3e60            Microsoft reserved partition
└─sda2      ntfs     1638549838547927                     e6637fda-1795-4936-87c1-4ff70aec6086 New Volume Basic data partition
sdb                                                                                                       
├─sdb1                                                    72f09ddb-9a15-48b5-b976-fa77e5e50ac0            Microsoft reserved partition
├─sdb2      ntfs     3EB8717FB871368D                     3a5d6099-e80b-4cec-85dd-8837e7712e57 New Volume Basic data partition
├─sdb3      vfat     77B0-A520                            299318df-05c8-408c-9ae6-26d536f15c5f            EFI System Partition
└─sdb4      ext4     e6f0548c-16b9-4aaa-959a-c66d9eb76d85 748b3db1-5343-483f-97a1-f90de6000eca            
nvme0n1                                                                                                   
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     4CDC-83EA                            cebfb099-1588-49a0-8c36-aa656fd658f7 SYSTEM     EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p2                                               dbf53fd2-5db6-453b-aecb-349e9ec689e4            Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs     E6A8DCF8A8DCC867                     725ed164-81ff-4fa5-9340-f6a610e27a8e Windows    Basic data partition
└─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     2816DD3316DD032C                     0eff7948-b5b3-41d7-bf7a-ffb702d178c8 Recovery   Basic data partition

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1                  64.1M  33% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p3                 172.8G  63% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p4                  99.8M  80% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
/dev/sda2                      236.8G  75% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sdb2                       98.1G   0% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb2
/dev/sdb4                      219.9G  82% /

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________


=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid e6f0548c-16b9-4aaa-959a-c66d9eb76d85 root hd1,gpt4 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

===================== sdb3/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid e6f0548c-16b9-4aaa-959a-c66d9eb76d85 root hd1,gpt4 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sdb4/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   e6f0548c-16b9-4aaa-959a-c66d9eb76d85
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-41-generic   e6f0548c-16b9-4aaa-959a-c66d9eb76d85
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-40-generic   e6f0548c-16b9-4aaa-959a-c66d9eb76d85
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-71-generic   e6f0548c-16b9-4aaa-959a-c66d9eb76d85
Windows Boot Manager (on nvme0n1p1)   osprober-efi-4CDC-83EA
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sdb4/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb4 during installation
UUID=e6f0548c-16b9-4aaa-959a-c66d9eb76d85 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=77B0-A520  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1

======================= sdb4/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

==================== sdb4: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
1279.806030273 = 1374.181261312 boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 930.867218018 = 999.511064576  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
 930.867218018 = 999.511064576  boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-71-generic                 1
 845.305301666 = 907.639656448  boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-40-generic                 2
1615.883426666 = 1735.041617920 boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-41-generic                 1
1615.883426666 = 1735.041617920 boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
 728.184074402 = 781.881696256  boot/initrd.img                                8
 728.184074402 = 781.881696256  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-71-generic              8
 928.455764771 = 996.921786368  boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-40-generic              1
 930.572879791 = 999.195021312  boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-41-generic              2
 930.572879791 = 999.195021312  boot/initrd.img.old                            2

===================== sdb4: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Apr 15  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Apr 15  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14180 Apr 15  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Apr 15  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Apr 15  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Jul  2  2022 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Jan 13  2021 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr 15  2022 41_custom
```

Comment: set `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` in grub

Comment: I uncomment that line in the grub file and it did not seem to change anything.

Comment: Does Windows directly boot from UEFI boot menu often f12, but varies by brand. Windows often turns fast start up back on, setting hibernation flag. That mean Ubuntu cannot see Windows partitions. So check settings in Windows.

Comment: I can't get any boot menu to show up.  If I try f keys it my monitor will never show anything and the computer doesn't load any operating system.  It just sits idle.

Comment: If you press escape right after vendor UEFI/BIOS screen, but just before grub menu should appear, do you then get grub menu? Can then boot recovery mode? What brand/model system? What video card/chip?

Comment: @user1695947 sure you did do `sudo update-grub` after that? sorry for asking, it's easy to forget to do it.

Comment: @Andra I did remember to do that because there is a reminder at the top of the grub file.

Comment: @oldfred, I have a blank screen until the Ubuntu logo pops up.  I did discover if I hit f12 the grub screen is activated, but I can not see it.  If I hit the down arrow twice and enter twice on a blank screen it does boot my windows.  My video cart is an rtx Nvidia card.

Comment: what if you uncomment `#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` line?

Comment: Down arrow once give you recovery mode boot? And then you can install the correct default nVidia driver for your card. You turn on Internet & use terminal. `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`  When installing better to use Safe Boot and choose to install the optional restricted drivers which will then install nVidia driver (and anyothers).